# Buffering the input to a passive RC integrator used to measure magnetic flux density

Tags: transformer, buffer, integrator, magnetic-flux

Note: this is part of a larger [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381009/magnetic-field-strength-and-flux-density-from-hysteresis-curve) which I was asked to separate into subquestions.
Other subquestions: [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389686/cutoff-frequency-of-passive-rc-integrator-used-to-measure-magnetic-flux-density) and [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389689/scaling-of-magnetic-field-strength-and-flux-density-measurments-and-shape-of-hys)

---

I'm using the method outlined [here](https://meettechniek.info/passive/magnetic-hysteresis.html) to measure the induced magnetic flux density in a toroidal transformer made of [Nanoperm](https://www.magnetec.de/fileadmin/pdf/data-sheets/m-083.pdf) (additional datasheets [here](http://www.coolblue-mhw.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Magnetec-2010-Catalog.pdf) and [here](https://www.magnetec.de/fileadmin/pdf/werkstoffkennlinien_nano_e.pdf)). I am trying to adapt the method to use a passive integrator rather than the op-amp integrator described in the tutorial. (I tried building the active one but it was giving me issues.)

The diagram of my circuit is given below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNVDvO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where I am varying the input frequency of V1 to be either 50 Hz (as reported in the datasheets to measure hysteresis), 350 Hz, and 380 Hz, and I am varying R2 to be either 5 kOhm, 10 kOhm, 27 kOhm, or 37 kOhm. Note that the signal generator is connected to an audio amplifier capable of driving large currents. A result from one of my experiments is shown here:

[image]

For more details about the experiment and results, please see my original larger [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381009/magnetic-field-strength-and-flux-density-from-hysteresis-curve).

While the shape of the hysteresis loop looks somewhat similar to that of the loops reported in the data sheet, it is orders of magnitude off in terms of both H and B. I posted a related question about this possibly being attributed to the way I was calculating H and B and/or to the fact that the gain of the RC integrator at the frequencies I'm looking at being much less than 1. I'm also wondering, **since I'm using a passive integrator, does the EMF induced in the measurement coil need to be buffered before being fed into the integrator?**

Comment: Is R1 << Rp on primary

Comment: Rp is 200 mOhms, and R1 is 400 mOhms, so no, R1 is > Rp.

Comment: Then reduce by orders of magnitude

Comment: Doesn’t the impedance of the coil increase when AC signals are passed through it? Because Z = |R + jwL|?

Comment: Yes as long as the IR drop is neglible and V-s integral is driven to saturation

Answer (score 1):

> I'm also wondering, since I'm using a passive integrator, does the EMF
>   induced in the measurement coil need to be buffered before being fed
>   into the integrator?

In short, yes because it eliminates the need to account for the losses in the resistor.

Without having to invoke circuit theory for a lossy secondary, to measure B we need to measure V as accurately as possible, which means open loop.

$$B = \frac{\Phi}{A}$$ and $$ V_s = \frac{d\Phi}{dt}*N_s $$

if you draw current from the loop then you need to account for the energy loss, which would mean factoring in a current into these equations because the voltage drop on the secondary would need to be accounted for. Much easier to use a high impedance measurement on the secondary.

In all of the hysteresis measuring curve circuits I have seen only high impedance integrator (which implies active).

Comment: Thanks, @laptop2d. Would one of these work: http://i.stack.imgur.com/N4RV4.png or http://i.stack.imgur.com/zpZ9w.png. I ask because I tried using the integrator given in the tutorial (https://meettechniek.info/passive/magnetic-hysteresis.html, section "Measuring arrangement with an analog oscilloscope") but I was getting really large current draws and eventually gave up. I also tried the op-amp integrator on Wikipedia, which also failed; however, I did not buffer that input to the integrator. Would buffering the input to the integrator, as shown in my second link, make a difference?

Comment: Yeah, I should have posted one of those links

Comment: Here is another one: http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/BHCkt/index.html

Comment: Thanks so much, @laptop2d. Should R1, R2, and R4 be 68, 1, and 10 ohms, respectively? I just see 68R, 1R, and 10R on my computer. Also how important is the material the capacitors are made of?